# Error on upgrading from Spring data neo4j 3.3.2.RELEASE to 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

Its a spring boot app and I was using spring data neo4j 3.3.2.RELEASE. It was working fine. As soon as I changed the version to 4.0.0.RELEASE, its giving the following errors:

```
[WARN] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer@147398c7:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':Injection of autowireddependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowire method:public voidorg.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
throws java.lang.Exception; nestedexception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expressionparsing failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privateorg.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsServicecom.movements.jhipster.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privatecom.movements.jhipster.repository.SecurityUserRepositorycom.movements.jhipster.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityUserRepository': Invocation ofinit method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':Injection of autowireddependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowire method:public voidorg.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
throws java.lang.Exception; nestedexception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expressionparsing failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privateorg.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsServicecom.movements.jhipster.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privatecom.movements.jhipster.repository.SecurityUserRepositorycom.movements.jhipster.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityUserRepository': Invocation ofinit method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:209)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:165)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:160)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:143)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:74)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:234)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:96)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.doStart(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:85)
~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:784)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:72)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:389)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:135)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.movements.jhipster.Application.main(Application.java:72) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Could not autowire method: public voidorg.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
throws java.lang.Exception; nestedexception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expressionparsing failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privateorg.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsServicecom.movements.jhipster.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privatecom.movements.jhipster.repository.SecurityUserRepositorycom.movements.jhipster.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityUserRepository': Invocation ofinit method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:649)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     ... 56 common framesomitted Caused by:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expressionparsing failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privateorg.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsServicecom.movements.jhipster.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection ofautowired dependencies failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could notautowirefield: privatecom.movements.jhipster.repository.SecurityUserRepositorycom.movements.jhipster.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository;nested exception isorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Errorcreating bean with name 'securityUserRepository': Invocation ofinit method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1365)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     ... 58 common framesomitted
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you did was update the version of SDN, then you're bound to get errors.

SDN4 has been completely re-written from scratch to use Cypher-based interactions favouring client-server mode and there are a lot of fundamental incompatibilities between 4 and 3 as a result of this.

The migration guide for upgrading is here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#migration

Comment: I have already followed this guide and made the required changes including the shift to ogm library. Still its giving the above error.

Comment: If the migration guide isn't working for you then you've probably got some conflicting versions of Spring classes on your classpath.  I'd guess this is a result of SDN4 bringing in newer versions of Spring artefacts that clash with your old ones.  Try to omit any 3.3.2.RELEASE Spring dependencies from other sources.